# Why does the quantum system transit to another eigenstate instead of arbitrary state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am trying to figure out why the quantum system would transit to another eigenstate instead of an arbitrary state.
Here is the statement in the book `principle of quantum mechanics` by Dirac, which uses the perturbation method to analyze the transition problem. At first, the system is at an eigenstate `|a'>` of unperturbed Hamiltonian `E`, the perturbated Hamiltonian is `H=E+V`.
What confuses me is why the sum of `P<a' a''>` would be 1. Why does the system have to transit into another eigenstate of the unperturbed Hamiltonian? And in reality, the atomic spectrum indeed shows that the transition to another eigenstate is the only possible transition. Does it mean that I have to take the measurement effect into consideration to explain why the atomic spectrum?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arbitrary state is usually expanded in terms of eigenstates.  In this specific case, this expansion would be conveniently done in terms of energy eigenstates, and the problem of transition probability to an arbitrary state then becomes the problem of a sum of transitions to eigenstates.  Of course, the sum of all transition probabilities from the initial state to any possible final state (including the initial state itself) must be $1$ since probabilities should always sum to $1$.

Comment: but the book says `P(a' a'')` is the probability of transition from `a'` to `a''`, and in reality, the atomic spectrum indeed shows that the transition to another eigenstate is the only possible transition. Does it mean that I have to take the measurement effect into consideration to explain why the atomic spectrum?

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand your point.  Since energy eigenstates are taken as basis functions, the initial and final states are usually taken to be energy eigenstates, as is the case here.  In general under perturbation the system will not transition to a single eigenstate, but to many of them (as allowed by selection rules).  So if your final state - for whatever reason - is not an energy eigenstate, you expand it in terms of these eigenstates and sum the transition probabilities.

Comment: Of course there might be additional energy considerations that restrict the possible final states, *viz* a perturbation that is at a frequency so that $\hbar \omega=E_i-E_f$, in which case you transition to eigenstates of specific energies.

Comment: Thanks, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

The system does not have to transition to another eigenstate. However if I make a measurement of the final energy I must get exactly one answer, so the probability of these possible measurement outcomes must be 1. In mathematical terms this nothing more than the observation that the Hamiltonian is a Hermitian operator, so its eigenstates form a complete basis, and the final state $T|\alpha'\rangle$ should be normalized.